# Background color is covering my image

Tags: css, html

I'm learning HTML/CSS and am stuck on this annoying problem:

When I put in a background color, it overlaps my image. My image link isn't broken it just shows the border.

image code:

```
<img src "Koala.png" alt = "Koalas" width = "200" height = "200">
```

background color:

```
    body { background-color: rgb(0, 102, 0)}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a missing =

```
<img src="Koala.png" alt = "Koalas" width = "200" height = "200">
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have your background color first and then put your image the computer reads the code top to bottom.

Comment: It's really hard to parse what you are saying. Please [edit] your answer to describe in detail what you mean. You can also give a code example.